# Waterproof overshoes on Platform Pedals with pins

Tags: shoes, rain, pedals-flat

Are there Overshoes designed to last on Platform Pedals with pins? How long would a "normal" overshoe last on platform pedals before it shreds?

Sofar I've been doing fine with some plastic and scotch tape but the appearance is atrocious.

Comment: The free shower caps you get at hotels are the preferred shoe cover for cheapskates. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that most cycling shoe covers are made for clipless and only have a small cutout for the cleat. They'd get shredded by walking too much or using platform pedals. You could use [hiking gaiters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaiters) instead.

Alternatively, these [delightful DIY shoe covers](http://www.cyclelicio.us/2006/12/diy-shoe-covers.html) are open on the bottom, waterproof, and made with things found around the house.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When riding in a torrential downpour, my rain setup is **gumboots on the feet**.

For pants I wear some yellow PVC plastic overtrousers that go over the gumboots.

Above that is a plastic jacket with long sleeves to cover the hands/gloves.

The head and face is most exposed - a helmet on top doesn't do much because of vents, so I throw a cheap showercap on top.

For the back of the neck I wear a buff ( a hollow cloth tube) and it just gets wet.

I wish I had a visor for my helmet - that would help protect the glasses.

Main problem of all this is that it doesn't breathe very well, so I get to work wet inside from sweating if I ride too fast.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but please consider Velominati rule #5

Comment: @AzulShiva yeah - but commuting to work, I want to get there moderately presentable.  Totally different on a race or similar.