# What kind of overshoes can I use with a large touring SPD cycling shoe such as the Giro Rumble VR?

Tags: shoes

I got myself a [Giro Rumble VR](https://www.giro.com/p/rumble-vr-mountain-bike-shoes/350060000200000024.html) size EU 46/UK 11/US 12 and it has been a good shoe.

However, since they are very breathable, my feet are getting too cold at around 5 deg C, and I tried to get a regular road shoe cover for them, such as the [dhb Extreme Weather Neoprene Overshoe](https://www.wiggle.co.uk/dhb-extreme-weather-neoprene-overshoe).

But as can be seen from the photos, the Giro is basically as large as regular sneakers, and it was impossible to make the L-sized covers fit it, and I don't think XL would have been large enough either.

Is there any other cover I could get that would work better? Or do I have to just buy warmer/more standard sized MTB shoes?

Related: [Waterproof overshoes on Platform Pedals with pins](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/45028/waterproof-overshoes-on-platform-pedals-with-pins)

**Edit**

I'm not in the mood for DIY (doing enough of that already), so I just got myself a standard sized [dhb Dorica MTB Shoe](https://www.wiggle.co.uk/dhb-dorica-mtb-shoe) and that worked with the cover. I got the non-extreme one though. This was an improvement, but it is still a bit cold when nearing zero. I might get a toe warmer as well at some point. The Giro will be reserved for 10 degrees +. One advantage of the Dorica is that it is easier to clean due to leather-like cover, especially when you can jus wash the cover separately.

Comment: Those Madisons in XL should fit you better than me, in that case

Comment: BTW if you're finding it cold in the dry, try more windproof socks.  2 thin pairs an be better than 1 thicker pair.  Also taping up the vents in the soles can help (wet or dry)

Comment: @ChrisH thanks, I'll keep those ideas in mind! Yes, primary concern is dry cold to start with.

Answer (score 3):

You need overshoes specifically designed for MTB shoes. Note that most of them would say *Road Compatible: Yes, MTB Compatible: Yes* but they are typically optimised for road shoes. I have the **Shimano S3000X NPU + overshoes** which are marketed as MTB overshoes and they are great, although it looks like they are hard to find nowadays in reasonable sizes.

Comment: They're also neoprene, which is stretchier than the typical material, but also warmer.  I wonder how they behave in the wet - all my neoprene stuff is wetsuits which let the water in, but allow it to stay there and warm up

Comment: They are OK in the wet. Obviously feet will get wet after a few hours of rain mostly due to water going down from the legs (that's a common issue even with waterproof boots and for which I've never been able to find a proper solution).

Comment: You'll never get round water running down your legs.  Showerproof legwarmers worn *over* the shoe covers will buy you a little time, or keep out light rain. I also have thin ankles so the seal is poor at the top.  But I was thinking more of the amount of water held in the fabric - do they get heavy, if so do they stay heavy or dry out when the weather improves.  I may try something similar for my next pair

Comment: I don't recall them ever being soaked in water, but that's a good point..

Answer (score 3):

I have the same shoes in UK12/EU47/US13.  I have some XL [Madison Sportive](https://www.leisurelakesbikes.com/shoes/pgr/madison-sportive-pu-thermal-overshoes-black__7070) overshoes, and they've survived a couple of years. I recently ripped them putting them on over my other shoes (an old pair of sadly discontinued Specialized Cadet), but not beyond repair, and it might have been caused by the bits that touch the ground being rather worn and therefore not reinforcing the upper.

It is a process of jiggling and pulling to get them over the shoes - I allow an extra 5 minutes to get ready if I know I'm putting them on (it doesn't take quite that long)

I also, in my commuting bag, have a pair of [Eager brand](https://www.gbcycles.co.uk/p/37890/Eager-Waterproof-Overshoe) overshoes, that owe more to hiking gaiters.  They're floppy rather than stretchy, and don't really look the part, but they're quick to put on and off, and work fairly well.  I've only been lightly mocked for them once, when at a gathering of proper cyclists, and by someone who was probably waiting for the chance.

Here are the 2 shoe covers: floppy Eager on the left, tight Madison on the right.
[image]

Comment: I'm glad to hear from someone that also has a Giro Rumble. BTW, the Madison shoes you mentioned, do they open completely on the back? Or is there a part in the ankle that does not open?

Comment: There's a part at the heel/ankle that doesn't open.  The Eager ones do open fully, which is why I chose them originally and still use them for commuting.  Mine are a UK 13 and may even be oversized for my shoes

Comment: The main big problem with over-shoes is that they are meant for riding and are poorly when walking, the sole shredding very easily. Having been there I've opted for a pair of ankle-high membrane winter shoes. (An alternative being seal-skin socks although they are less likely to fit into summer shoes.)

Comment: @Carel you're right there.  I don't tend to walk much on rides, and have had issues with waterproof shoes filling right up.  I'd rather have them drain

Comment: @ChrisH: I've just taken a look at my waterproof shoes: the holes where the cleats are attached are not entirely covered and certainly allow the shoes to drain. A waterproof top and a tightly closing ankle are more important since most of the water comes from above, mainly running down the legs. If you walk through a puddle though ... And if you chose them one size larger, the sealskin socks will fit in as well!

Comment: @Carel interesting. I tape up the soles in some of mine (except I wore a different pair yesterday and had to push the tourer over puddly grass). Standing water on the road spraying up is also an issue with sole vents, even with good mudguards. So I like a vented upper under an overshoe. You're right about ankle seals. That's an area I have trouble with - big feet but thin ankles. I'd probably have to put drysuit seals over the top.